# How to move a canvas element on top of another canvas element

Tags: javascript, canvas, dom-events, mouseevent

I have 2 `canvas` elements on top of each other and i want to move the canvas element on top on mouse drag but it produces weird results.

This is my code for the events (the variable `cvs` is the `canvas` element which is on top of other canvas element)

```js
  var drag = false;
  cvs.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
    drag = true;
  });
  
  cvs.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
    drag = false;
  });

  cvs.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    if (drag) {
      const rect = cvs.getBoundingClientRect()
      const x = event.clientX - rect.left;
      const y = event.clientY - rect.top;
      cvs.style.left = x + "px";
      cvs.style.top = y + "px";
      console.log(x, y);
    }
  });
```

When I drag the top `canvas` it starts to flicker back-and-forth between 2 positions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a glance, it looks like you are using a relative value to set an absolute position.

So, first iteration, the left position updates to x, then the next iteration you subtract the last value of x from the mouse position. I think this is going to move it on and off screen.

say, clientX is at 100, and left is at 10.

T1 -> x = 100 - 10 = 90,
T2 -> x = 100 - 90 = 10.

Hence the "flickering"

What you want to do, is take the relative movement value of the mouse and move the element by the same amount.

So on mouse down, record the mouse initial position and element initial position.

Subtract the initial mouse position from the mouse position on each mouse move iteration, and assign the initial element position plus the relative change to the element.

```js
  var initialPosition = null
  var initialMouseCoords = null
  
  cvs.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
    initialPosition = cvs.getBoundingClientRect()
    initialMouseCoords = {clientX: event.clientX, clientY: event.clientY}
  });
  
  cvs.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
    initialPosition = null
    initialMouseCoords = null
  });

  cvs.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    if (initialMouseCoords) {
      const dx = event.clientX - initialMouseCoords.clientX;
      const dy = event.clientY - initialMouseCoords.clientY;

      cvs.style.left = initialPosition.left + dx;
      cvs.style.top = initialPosition.top + dy;
      
      console.log(dx, dy);
    }
  });
```

Bare in mind there are drag events depending on your use case, you might want to explore that as an alternative.

Comment: This code is not working when the `canvas` is rotated. Do you know how to do that ?

Comment: You could use composition. Have the canvas element inside a div element, use the mouse positioning on the div, and rotate the canvas inside

Comment: It is actually working but when I drag the mouse for the first time then it suddenly jumps to a new location and then it works normally. I don't see any fault in the logic that should have caused that though. Also, I did not understand that can you explain a bit more.

Comment: Oh yeah, getClientBoundingRect() returns the element position relative to the viewport, left and top will be relative to it's parent element. If your canvas is not positioned as fixed in CSS, then you will need to use the original element left and top value.

Comment: instead of initialPosition = cvs.getBoundingClientRect()

Comment: Do initialPosition = {left: cvs.style.left, top: cvs.style.top}

Comment: You should set up a codepen for this -> https://codepen.io/

Comment: Thanks, will try